fire database document ID and row id using flutter
Is there a way to pick that document id that found int he picture?

Also is that auto created id is ID for the collection, or should i make a new field in the collection and name it ID and pushing it throw flutter?
In other way is that Ids in the picture is the same id of the data Row. Sorry for that miss i am new to Firebase and coming from my SQL.
Also can i use Firebase as SQL?

You have way too many questions and way too little details in your question. Limit yourself to a single question per post, to prevent it being closed as being too broad. On the first question: what does "picking a document ID" look like? Do you have code that can highlight what you're trying to do?
